# Select car of max(date) for every employee

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I would need a code for the following problem:

I have a table like this:

| Employee | Year | Month | Car |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 2021 | 9 | Ford |
| Tom | 2021 | 10 | Ford |
| Tom | 2021 | 11 | Ford |
| Tom | 2021 | 12 | Renault |
| Tom | 2022 | 1 | Renault |
| Mark | 2021 | 12 | VW |
| Mark | 2022 | 1 | VW |
| Mark | 2022 | 2 | VW |
| Joe | 2021 | 8 | Opel |
| Joe | 2021 | 9 | Tesla |
| Joe | 2021 | 10 | Ferrari |

And I would need the car used by the employee for the last possible date. So the result should be:

| Employee | Car |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | Renault |
| Mark | VW |
| Joe | Ferrari |

With:

```sql
select employee, max(year || month) from table.cars
group by employee
```

I get the max(date) for every employee, but I do not know how to join the cars to the max(date).

How can I get the result I want?

Comment: What is the type of Year, Month columns? Sample data look like char.

Comment: You can check out the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e75ed2026701909e2df7193616b5d45b)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
with t as
(
  select *,
        row_number() over (partition by employee order by year desc, month desc) rn
  from cars 
) 
select employee, car 
from t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: and `as` keyword is missing too if you notice

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function such as

```sql
SELECT Employee, Car
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                           (PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC) AS rn,
               c.*
          FROM cars c)
 WHERE rn = 1
```

provided that the data type of the year and month are of string type, then you can replace the part `ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC` with

`ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(TRIM(year)) DESC, TO_NUMBER(TRIM(month)) DESC`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select employee, car 
from ( 
        Select *, ROW_NUMBER(partition by employee order by year, month DESC) as row_number
        from cars
        )a
Where row_number = 1
```